# Issue deploying BIRT Report to Tomcat 9.0

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat, birt

I am using BIRT to generate reports of our data.  When using the internal Eclipse viewer it generates and displays fine.  When I deploy it to my localhost Tomcat 9.0 I get the following error in the log.

This also happens with the sample report the instructions I used to configure the environment but it doesn't happen with the "test" report that comes with the BIRT viewer.

```
INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service
Error parsing HTTP request header
Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException**: Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986  
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:456)  
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:380)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) 
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:796)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1372)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)  
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)  
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have started the Tomcat in Debug mode and this is what the log is saying.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jul/2017:15:05:38 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11458
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jul/2017:15:05:50 -0500] "GET /manager/html HTTP/1.1" 401 2536
127.0.0.1 - admin [30/Jul/2017:15:05:54 -0500] "GET /manager/html HTTP/1.1" 200 19627
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jul/2017:15:05:54 -0500] "GET /manager/images/tomcat.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 2066
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jul/2017:15:05:54 -0500] "GET /manager/images/asf-logo.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 19908
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jul/2017:15:05:59 -0500] "GET null null" 400 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jul/2017:15:06:37 -0500] "GET null null" 400 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jul/2017:15:11:10 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11458
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jul/2017:15:11:46 -0500] "GET null null" 400 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jul/2017:15:14:08 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11458
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jul/2017:15:14:28 -0500] "GET null null" 400 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jul/2017:15:14:45 -0500] "GET null null" 400 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jul/2017:15:14:48 -0500] "GET null null" 400 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jul/2017:15:14:49 -0500] "GET null null" 400 -
```

I am trying to find a way to upload the code sample without making this way too long.  For now, here is a link to the XML if that is ok?

https://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/examples/solution/SalesInvoice.rptdesign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved.  The instructions for placing the reports are wrong.  They need to go in the main folder for BIRT Viewer, not the \Report folder like the instructions say.